# Regex pattern only to find out string before first occurance of forward slash

Tags: java, regex

I am failing to create one regex pattern which will give me only the domain name of an URL.

Test String is:

> http://host.com/first/second

now, from the above string, I only want my regex to find:

> http://host.com

That is until the regex find the first single forward slash occurance in the string.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about reading [negated class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated). It will give you ability [to exclude `/`](https://www.regex101.com/r/3YLUDz/1)

Comment: What about: URI uri = URI.create("http://host.com/first/second");
    System.out.println(uri.getScheme()+"://"+uri.getHost()); ?

Comment: No @Gustave, i also thought about that. but my requirement was a bit different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may split by singular stashes (`(?<!\/)\/(?!\/)` - a slash not proceeded and not followed by a slash) and use the first part:

```
String input = "http://host.com/first/second";
String[] parts = input.split("(?<!\\/)\\/(?!\\/)");
System.out.print(parts[0]);
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/7Okn6C

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    (https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?\w+\.\w+
```

As tested here: https://regex101.com/r/1UQl9g/1